# postgres 9.3.6 very slow truncates on small table

Tags: postgresql, truncate

In Postgres 9.3.6, truncates against a table with <10 rows in it are regularly taking 2-3 minutes.

The truncate is stuck in waiting=f and state=idle in transaction for the duration of the delay.

Researching this online, the standard answer to this problem is lock contention, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.  This is happening on a CI host that is unloaded except for the CI tests.  According to pg_stat_activity, the truncate is the only statement running, and according to pg_locks there are no locks that have not been granted, so it doesn't appear to me that the truncate is being blocked waiting for a lock.

Additionally, I've checked the postgres log for deadlock errors and have found none.

(Note that we are using a truncate vs. 10 rows because this problem is happening during CI testing -- during normal production operation there are 10^6ish rows in this table, so truncation makes sense.  It's a working intermediate table that is truncated before each run of our ETL process.)

I'm not sure where to go from here -- any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Here's the output from the relevant queries:

```
warehouse=# select pid,usename,backend_start,xact_start,query_start,now()-query_start as wait_time,state_change,waiting,state,query from pg_stat_activity;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid           | 25123
usename       | dev
backend_start | 2015-04-13 23:25:47.728267+00
xact_start    | 2015-04-14 00:23:39.969074+00
query_start   | 2015-04-14 00:23:39.969074+00
wait_time     | 00:00:00
state_change  | 2015-04-14 00:23:39.969081+00
waiting       | f
state         | active
query         | select pid,usename,backend_start,xact_start,query_start,now()-query_start as wait_time,state_change,waiting,state,query from pg_stat_activity;
-[ RECORD 2 ]-+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid           | 5288
usename       | fk-etl
backend_start | 2015-04-14 00:21:20.913133+00
xact_start    | 2015-04-14 00:21:20.921312+00
query_start   | 2015-04-14 00:21:20.92142+00
wait_time     | 00:02:19.047654
state_change  | 2015-04-14 00:21:20.928318+00
waiting       | f
state         | idle in transaction
query         | TRUNCATE TABLE foo_schema.foo


warehouse=# select * from pg_locks;
warehouse=# SELECT relation::regclass as object, mode,granted,pid FROM pg_locks;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | 
mode    | ExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 2 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | pg_locks
mode    | AccessShareLock
granted | t
pid     | 25123
-[ RECORD 3 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | 
mode    | ExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 25123
-[ RECORD 4 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | foo_schema.foo_compound_idx
mode    | AccessExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 5 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | foo_schema.foo
mode    | ShareLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 6 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | foo_schema.foo
mode    | AccessExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 7 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | foo_schema.foo_pkey
mode    | AccessExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 8 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | pg_toast.pg_toast_10043463
mode    | ShareLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 9 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | pg_toast.pg_toast_10043463
mode    | AccessExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 10 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | pg_toast.pg_toast_10043463_index
mode    | AccessExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
-[ RECORD 11 ]--------------------------------------------------------------------------
object  | 
mode    | ExclusiveLock
granted | t
pid     | 5288
```

Answer (score 2):

```
state         | idle in transaction
query         | TRUNCATE TABLE foo_schema.foo
```

The `TRUNCATE` has completed, and the session is waiting for the next statement or for a `COMMIT`.

It sounds like this is an application-side issue, but it's impossible to say for sure with no information about what's running the `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: This is a very helpful insight! The application is a Pentaho Kettle transform and the truncate is being run by a table output step that is also inserting records.  I can see how it might be slow about issuing commits.  We'll refocus there.  Thanks!

Comment: ...and it turns out that we had a generate UUID step upstream that was blocking on /dev/random. When the table output step initialized, it ran the truncate, but it didn't commit the truncate until /dev/random spat out enough randomness to generate the UUID and actually sent it a row.